# Dismissing Multiple Alerts Bootstrap 5.3

Tags: bootstrap-5, alerts, dismissible

I have 2 alerts with the same content but slightly diffirent styles. One is set aside visible in desktop devices and above, the other for medium screens and below, is sticky bottom. They both share identical code, but their containers are diffirent. e.g.

```
<div id="desktop" class="d-none d-lg-block">
 <div class="alert alert-dismissible fade show">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="smaller-than-desktop" class="d-lg-none">
  <div class="alert alert-dismissible fade show">
   ...
   <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to dismiss both instanses by clicking the close buton of only the one of them?

I found out that the object that enters the dom last can do the job, not the same with the first one.
E.g.
if the smaller-than-desktop object comes last in the DOM, dismissing the alert, dismisses also the alert of the desktop object, while in the oposite, the desktop alert is dismissed, but the other is stil living.

Comment: you forgot to share code

Comment: edited and added. thank you

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using one alert and using a media query to apply different styles on a lg screen?

Comment: No, in fact that was the model of approach from the beggining, i kind of detoured on the way and thought of trying this. Its just that the two containers have a lot of diffirent styling depending on the media.